# Angular 14 SSR is giving an 'at XMLHttpRequest3.send()' error after being successfully compiled using the npm run dev:ssr command

Tags: server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular14, angular-ssr

I am implementing Angular Universal (SSR) in Angular 14. The application builds without any issues when I run npm run build:ssr. Furthermore, I can successfully compile it using npm run dev:ssr. However, when I attempt to access the application via the compiled URL (e.g., http://localhost:4200), it presents an error with the message 'at XMLHttpRequest.send()'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9V2Cf.png)

I encounter the same error when I run the npm run serve:ssr command.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyuL5.png)

Does this error have any relation to the ports, such as HTTP and HTTPS?

app.server.module.ts
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDrmg.png)

main.server.ts
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGh61.png)

tsconfig.server.json
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiqYe.png)

server.ts
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pvp7K.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcMhb.png)

Comment: Xhr doesn't exist in node. I think angular should be setting up a polyfill however...

Comment: In ASP.NET Core we can omit sending webrequests during SSR by using the `SupplyData` hook. [More info](https://pieterjandeclippel.medium.com/server-side-rendering-in-asp-net-core-angular-2022-version-7aaed8157976)